# weekCalendar, adding readOnly to events from json

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add readonly(no resize, drag or anything else) to already added, events created from JSON ?

Also I'm interested in ability of adding a setting or something which would remove or block adding new events on certain dates i.e sunday and friday.

I need to add readonly option to calendar event my json data looks like this for example:

```
events:[{"id":10182,
  "start":"2009-05-03T12:15:00.000+10:00",
  "end":"2009-05-03T13:15:00.000+10:00",
  "title":"Lunch with Mike"
},
```

As I understand to make event readOnly there's have to be a `readOnly : true` value in event object i.e

```
events:[{"id":10182,
  "start":"2009-05-03T12:15:00.000+10:00",
  "end":"2009-05-03T13:15:00.000+10:00",
  "title":"Lunch with Mike",
  readOnly : true
},
```

But it's not working, what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Well, I tried adding "readonly : true" to `dataEvets = events : [ ]` array.

Comment: Can you provide some demo, or code at least!

Comment: It's too big to post here is a link to project https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/wiki

Comment: Try to separate your code and isolate the problem, also you can try [Jsbin](jsbin.com) or [JsFiddle](jsfiddle.com) to make a demo of your problem. In any other case there is no way somebody can help you. Your question will soon be closed

Comment: Yes I understand it's hard to get answer from ones, who don't know this plugin, I was willing to get help from someone who already know or had any expierence with this plugin.

Comment: I suggest checking for JavaScript errors. The [**demo**](http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html) you seem to be using works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same question is over here with the soloution

[Jquery Week Calendar Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jquery-week-calendar/rmxZBcTHgZY/KY-mBMfF6PQJ)

Here is the helpful code snippet from Gildonei Mendes Anacleto Junior  on that page:

```
$('#calendar').weekCalendar({ 
        draggable : function(calEvent, $event) { 
                return calEvent.readOnly != true; 
                // You also can use return false; 
        }, 
        resizable : function(calEvent, $event) { 
                return calEvent.readOnly != true; 
                // You also can use return false; 
        } 
});
```